# Is there a "Reload in x Minutes" feature in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

I am recently trying Chrome on my XP machine, coming from Firefox which I found to be frustratingly slow.

However, one feature I REALLY appreciated in Firefox was the "Reload in x Minutes".

I cannot find anything similar in chrome. Is there a way to set this automated process up?

Comment: That's not a native feature of Firefox, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some [Chrome extensions](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/) out for this.

Try [ChromeReload](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/njoipeaphfnaplplihpbgndfojhdhmjo)

[image]

I personally like this one because it tells you how long is left until the page automatically refreshes. (For those like me with slight OCD tendencies :)

[image]

or there is [Auto-Reload](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ofojbjgaaddibdfpmmjeonahgbacejid) which has a few more options under the hood.

[image]

Please note: You need Google Chrome version 4 or higher to use extensions. The current version is 4. The development version is 5. Since Google Chrome automatically updates itself (in most cases), you should already be on 4.

You can find this out by clicking on the wrench icon on the right hand side and seeing if 'Extensions' is listed in the drop down menu.

Alternativelly just type `chrome://extensions/` in the URL address bar. You can then book mark this page if you so wish.

Comment: I tried chrome reload, but every time I followed a link on a reload enabled page, it removed the reload feature and I had to reset it.

I now have Auto-reload enabled, and, while I cannot set the interval in it because that is not yet implemented, I prefer it because it retains the reload feature in the tab no matter if I leave that exact page. I have on/off control and so I use this one for now. Thanks

Comment: I have switched my acceptance to Chromereload.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [**Chrome Refresh**](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aifhnlnghddfdaccgbbpbhjfkmncekmn) extension, might be just what you are looking for.

[image]

Ensure you have the [latest version](http://www.google.com/chrome) of Chrome installed, in order for extensions to work.

I use it myself, so I can vouch for it doing what it says on the tin.